# Find a Difference Between Items from Another Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a Summary sheet which looks at unique dates and determines how much time has passed between the last and first entries associated with those dates.  If only one entry than 0 time would be indicated.

**Master Sheet:**

[image]

**Summary Sheet:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a situation like this one:

[image]

This formula should do the trick:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(A:A=E1)*B:B,1)-AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(A:A=E1)*B:B,1)
```